# Using setup.py and requirements.txt to overwrite package with a github version?

Tags: python, github, setup.py, requirements.txt

I am working on a github project that will eventually be released on both conda and PyPl. Because of PyPl (and current development needs) I need to make the installation work using this command:
`python -m pip install -e .` (from inside the github cloned folder - pip 21)

However, my project has a dependency from a forked github repo. The problem I have is that I do not find a way to install the package from that fork using the command above, ....but I have to. Any trick I could find either got me nothing or the prod version of the repo. The only two things that worked are (1) manual or scripted launch of pip install [cannot do this, need setup.py to install things] (2) using conda [cannot rely on conda alone, I need the regular pip to work].

Can you please help me or point me in the right direction?

I use a `requirements.txt` that contains this line at the bottom:

```
...
-e git+https://github.com/jojurgens/pyqode.qt.git@master#egg=pyqode.qt
```

and a `setup.py` that contains this

```
with open(here / "requirements.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name="qiskit_metal",
    version="0.0.2",
    install_requires=requirements,
)
```

On execution I get this error:

```
...error in setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Parse error at "'-e git+h'": Expected W:(abcd...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I was finally able to find an answer. For who may need this info, here is what I did:

In `requirements.txt` I have changed the line to this:

```
pyqode.qt @ git+https://github.com/jojurgens/pyqode.qt.git#egg=pyqode.qt
```

that alone took care of the error.

That also solved my other (not described here) problem about "updating" the conda environment without corrupting it. So now I update the environment with just the same install command (as opposed to the update command, which does not work) `python -m pip install -e .`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should specify is the version of Shapely on the requirements, for example `Shapely==<version>`. If you want to install from differente source (and not from pip), do it outside of requirements.txt. For that you can evoke a bash command inside of your python code.

Comment: please ignore shapely. that just happened to be the line above the github line, it is not part of the problem. I edited the case and removed it

Comment: Due to the need to make the package universal, embedding a subprocess in the setup.py is tricky. We tried and had to create a bunch of if statements to capture different OS, different releases, and I think it is still not generic enough. So I am hoping there is a cleaner way. Thoughts?

Comment: I will give you my experience as DevOps: This types of things should be done at the level of the infra configuration.  Create a installation script for your app (and this can be very generic) and do not  ties your App to what is done on the setup. You can use a python script anyway (or bash, chef, ...) and use the advantage of envolving the app in a virtual env.  I hope this can help you